# Как вытащить части из JSON из командной строки или bash-скрипта?

Tags: linux, парсер, perl

Нужно забирать погоду на один из сервисов. Изменился webapi и старый запрос не верен.

Из этого:

```pl
[{"Id":39496,"TerritoryId":1,"GismeteoId":2334,"GeoObjectName":"г.Уганда",
"DateRequest":"2020-01-28T08:00:06.103","DataDateTime":"2020-01-28 05:00:00",
"Temperature":-3.200000762939453,"Pressure":732,"Wind":"Северный","WindSpeed":
3.0,"Description":"Облачно, небольшой снег"}]
```

Спарсить: температура, ветер и давление.

Раньше было так:

```
cat $weather_file | grep Уганда | perl -pe 's/^.*Temperature>((-)?\d+).*/$1/' > $weather_home/temperature_uga_result

cat $weather_file | grep Уганда | perl -pe 's/.*Wind:(\d{1,2}).*/$1/' > $weather_home/wind_uga_result

cat $weather_file | grep Уганда | perl -pe 's/.*Pressure: (\d{1,3}).*/$1/' > $weather_home/atmosphere_uga_result
```

Answer (score 6):

Это можно сделать [с помощью утилиты jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/), которая есть в большинстве дистрибутивов:

```
$ cat example.json | jq -r '.[0].Temperature'
-3.200000762939453
$ cat example.json | jq -r '.[0].Pressure'
732
$ cat example.json | jq -r '.[0].Wind'
Северный
```

Или одним запросом:

```
jq -r '.[0] | "Температура: \(.Temperature)\nДавление: \(.Pressure)\nВетер: \(.Wind)"' example.json
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Проще единственным запросом: ```jq -r '.[0] | "Температура: \(.Temperature)\nДавление: \(.Pressure)\nВетер: \(.Wind)"' example.json```

Comment: *Useless use of cat...*

Comment: @0andriy подразумевается что у автора там не cat, а curl